# How to extract the hidden value in imacros

Tags: scripting, imacros

I want to extract the verification code in attribute value, what the code? i dont understand in this problem

[Look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ickGW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps, And not too late.

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:HIDDEN ATTR=NAME:_RequestVerificationToken* EXTRACT=TXT